# Flickering effect while updated - Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've created component to search posts from API by query from URL, but if I change the query I receive strange flickering effect. Count of flicks grows by one after every change. How to solve it? Vue Devtools shows that loadPosts() is called: 1time, 2 times, 3times and so on. Where's the mistake? Reloading component gives the same effect.

```js
<template>
    <v-app>
        <main-header/>
        <v-layout class="mx-auto default--container">
            <v-flex xs12 ma-2>
                <h2 class="display-2 text-xs-center main-page--header">
                    <span class="text__red">W</span>yniki wyszukiwania dla:
                    <span class="text__red">{{this.$route.query.s}}</span>
                </h2>
                <article-list-sample v-for="i in articles.length" :key="`${i}`" />
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <main-footer />
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    import MainHeader from './MainHeader';
    import MainFooter from './MainFooter';
    import ArticleListSample from './ArticleListSample';
    import API from '../api';
    export default {
        components: {
            ArticleListSample,
            MainFooter,
            MainHeader
        },
        name: 'search',
        data: () => ({
            articles: []
        }),
        methods: {
            loadPosts() {
                API.get(`posts?search=${this.$route.query.s}`)
                    .then(response => this.articles = response['data'])
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadPosts();
        },
        updated() {
            this.loadPosts();
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just need to add watcher instead of updated() method.

```js
watch: {
            '$route' () {
                this.loadPosts();
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on this, the infinite loop was created because updated was triggered whenever you were changing this.articles which would then start an other asynchronous call.